# How to programmatically RESUME IIS website?

Tags: c#, iis, web, directoryentry

I'm using the following code to start website when it is stopped.

```
DirectoryEntry DE = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/{0}", siteID));
if ((Int32)DE.InvokeGet("ServerState") != MD_SERVER_STATE_STARTED)
     DE.Invoke("Start");
```

But it works only if the website is stopped and not works if it is PAUSED. How can i start the website if it is in the PAUSED state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resume a site from the `Paused` state you should invoke the `Continue` method.